# No persistent session when connecting to API on different host

Tags: ruby, session, websocket, coffeescript

I am sending a websocket connection to the API server on a different host:

```
new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000")
```

Whereas my front end is hosted on `localhost:8080`.

Inside my API's websocket connection handler I'm able to set a key on the `session` (with Sinatra's `enable :sessions`) but every time I refresh the html page, the data is lost.

Is there some requirement for sessions that the front end share the same host as the server? Or is there some way I can get around this? By the way, the front end is running on a Webpack server (Node).

I also tried adding a cross_origin allowance for the API's root route `http://localhost:3000` and then doing this in the client (this example in coffeescript):

```
$.get "http://localhost:3000", ->
  new Websocket("ws://localhost:3000")
```

My thinking was that maybe the session needed to be "initialized" over `http://` instead of `ws://` but it didn't work either. The session didn't work for the `$.get "http://localhost:3000"` request either. Refreshing the page shows that the session clears each time.

Comment: Sessions are going to be based on cookies, so the issue is probably the persistence of the session cookie.  When you use a host/port different than that of the web page, then your session cookie becomes what is known as a 3rd party cookie and there are different security rules and settings for 3rd party cookies.  I would guess that your settings or add-ons are blocking the persistence of 3rd party cookies.  plain webSockets by themselves work fine on cross origin connections, but if you're trying to attach a session cookie when established, then that would require persistence of the cookie.

Comment: So do I add code to the client or server?

Comment: You have to first look into whether 3rd party cookies are being retained by your client.  If not, then you have to either fix the settings in the client so they are retained or stop using a separate origin so you don't run afoul of 3rd party cookie settings.

Comment: I see so it is determined on a per-browser basis and theres no way I can force it to be whitelisted. Probably will end up combining the apps then

Comment: cookies are kept in clients.  So, it is purely client-side functionality and settings that decides whether to keep 3rd party cookies or not.  Nothing you can do to influence it on the server other than stop relying on 3rd party cookies.  I do have an idea for how you could work around relying on 3rd party cookies if you want me to post that as an answer (it requires more than can fit into a comment).

Comment: You'd have to communicate a sessionID back to the client and have the client store it as a first party cookie.  Then, a connecting page would get the sessionID from the first party cookie and send it as part of the websocket connecting URL and the server could then hook it up to that particular session.  This would require client and server code changes, but could be done.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful and makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've discussed in comments, you probably have a problem with 3rd party session cookies in the browser.

Here's a scheme that you could use to work around it.

1. Client makes webSocket connection for the first time.
2. Server sends a webSocket message back with sessionID in it.
3. Client stores sessionID in a first party cookie (e.g. a cookie in the host web page).
4. User hits refresh.
5. Web page checks to see if it has a webSocket session cookie in the cookies for the host page.  If so, it constructs a URL for the webSocket connection that includes that session ID `new Websocket("ws://localhost:3000?session=xyslkfas")
6. When server accepts webSocket connection, it checks the query parameters to see if there is already a session being specified.  If so and that session is still valid, it hooks up that connection to that session.  If not, it creates a new session and goes back to step 2.

Comment: **Note**: This approach introduces a security risk unless the session ID is rotated *every* connection. Otherwise, the session ID is logged with the request by most intermediaries and can be easily hijacked. It's true that sessions aren't that secure to begin with, but I would avoid attaching any information to the request URL.

Comment: @Myst - Good point.  sessionIDs should always expire and not last particularly long.  Or, once the sessionID is used for the relogin, a new one can be coined and sent back to the client just as in step 2 and the old one invalidated.  Or, you could accept the webSocket connection without a sessionID with a reconnect query parameter boolean and then require the credential be sent within a few seconds before any other messages are allowed to be processed (thus avoiding the logging).  There are lots of ways to make it more secure depending upon what you need/want to protect against.

Comment: @Myst - Also, given that the OP is not talking about any authentication here at all, I think this sessionID is only so the server can associate a reconnecting webSocket with the previous session info.  So, this doesn't appear to be an authenticated connection at all so security must not be the main issue here.  If there is auth info, then the reconnect can just submit the auth info and solve the problem that way.

Comment: @Myst Thankfully I was keen enough to realize the token would need to be refreshed every page reload. To prevent URL snooping I'm using wss and https for the deployed version.